# Given that exactly 2 Jacks appear, what is the expected number of Aces that appear?

Tags: probability

Pick 5 cards from standard 52 cards without replacement. Given that exactly 2 jack cards appear, find the expected number of ace cards that appear.

ATTEMPT

Let $X$ be number of aces chosen and $Y$ number of jacks chosen so we want find $E(X|Y=2)$. In the definition we have

$$ E(X|Y=2) = \sum_{x=0}^5 x \frac{ p_{XY}(x,2) }{p_Y(2)} $$

First we find

$$ p_{XY}(1,2) = P(X=1 \cap Y=2) = \frac{ {4 \choose 1 } {4 \choose 2} {13 \choose 2} }{ {52 \choose 5} } $$

$$ p_{XY}(2,2) = P(X=2 \cap Y=2) = \frac{ {4 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2} {13 \choose 2} }{ {52 \choose 5} } $$

$$ p_{XY}(3,2) = P(X=3 \cap Y=2) = \frac{ {4 \choose 3 } {4 \choose 2} {13 \choose 2} }{ {52 \choose 5} } $$

after $x=3$ we have $0$ since we cant have more that 5 cards. finally we find

$$ p_Y(2) = P(Y=2) = \frac{ {4 \choose 2}{13 \choose 3} }{ {52 \choose 5} } $$

Now, pluggin in into the first equation should give the answer. Is this a correct approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: Since the question states "*given* two jacks appear..." your question boils down to "What is the expected number of aces in the remaining three cards?"  So take the probability you get 0 aces in three out of 50 cards and multiply by 0, take the probability you get exactly 1 ace out of 50 cards and multiply by 1, take... [up to three aces] and add them up.

Comment: Looks like a job for indicator variables and linearity of expectation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think you mean $0$ aces in three out of $48$ cards, not $50$ cards.  We are given that exactly two jacks appeared and no more than that.  This is different than the problem than the one where we are instead given that the jack of hearts and the jack of clubs appear (*and possibly additional jacks beyond that*).

Comment: @JMoravitz:  No.  *Given* that two jacks appear, then there are 50 (not 48) cards remaining from which another three will be chosen.  Perhaps 0 aces will be chosen;  perhaps exactly 1 ace will be chosen; perhaps exactly 2 aces will be chosen; perhaps exactly 3 aces will be chosen.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Consider a smaller example where we have a deck of just five cards... the four jacks and one ace.  We draw a hand of size three.  We are told that among the three cards we drew, we drew exactly two jacks.  Now... what will the probability be of having drawn an ace in that scenario?  $1$?  Or $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Again, you are making the mistake of accidentally leaving the additional jacks that aren't in the hand as being possible draws from the deck.  It should be instead "What is the expected number of aces in a hand of size three from a standard deck where all of the jacks are missing, i.e. a deck of 48 cards?"

Comment: Oh... OK.  I overlooked "exactly" two jacks were chosen.  So we don't allow the case that another jack is chosen.  Sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, pluggin in into the first equation should give the answer. Is this a correct approach to tackle this problem?

Yes, that *would* work, although your evaluations are off.

$p_{\small Y}(2) =\mathsf P(Y{=}2) = \left.\binom 4 2\binom {48}{3}\middle/\binom{52}{5}\right.$ is the probability for selecting $2$ from $4$ Jacks and $3$ from $48$ non-Jacks when selecting $5$ from $52$ cards.

$p_{\small X,Y}(x,2) =\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}2) =\left.\binom 42\binom 4x\binom {44}{3-x}\middle/\binom{52}{5}\right. $ is the probability for selecting $2$ from $4$ Jacks, $x$ from $4$ aces, and $3-x$ from $44$ non-Jack-or-Aces when selecting $5$ from $52$ cards.

Thus $p_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid 2) =\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}2) =\left.\binom 4x\binom {44}{3-x}\middle/\binom{48}{3}\right. $ is the probability for selecting $x$ from $4$ aces, and $3-x$ from $44$ non-Jack-or-Aces when selecting $3$ from $48$ non-Jack cards.

Alternatively, I place the hand with the non-Jack cards face down on the table, and the two Jacks face up, asserting they are the only Jacks in the hand.   I point to one of the face down cards and ask: What is the expectation that *this* card is an Ace?     I do this for each from the three face-down cards in the hand, and the answer is the same.

So, by using the *Linearity of Expectation*, the expected count for Aces in the hand when given exactly two Jacks are in the hand, will be...